# Reading Guitar Pro files

Tags: c#, java, .net, vb.net, guitar

I was wondering if anybody had heard of a library, preferably a .NET assembly, but Java will do as wel, that allows you to read the data in a Guitar Pro file (.gp3-gp4-gp5)

I have this gigantor of a folder with about 50.000 song files, and would really love to write something that can actually archive all these files, for easier searching. And basic information like the tuning of the instruments in the song would be very useful parameters to retrieve from the file and add to the database.

I have searched the web but have yet to find anything like this, or a file definition for writing my own parser.

Thank you in advance for any information on the subject.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[TuxGuitar](http://tuxguitar.herac.com.ar/) is an open source Java application that includes classes that read Guitar Pro files. If should be probably more that sufficient for reading basic metadata.

Your other option is using [reverse-engineered file format documentation](http://dguitar.sourceforge.net/GP4format.html) - there's one from DGuitar project.

Your third option is trying to re-use some code from [KGuitar](http://kguitar.sf.net) project, that also include Guitar Pro 3/4/5 files importing clasess, but it's in C++ and Qt.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see how far I'll get with TuxGuitar.

Answer (score 10):

Please look through my open source project that is written in C# for Windows Phone7:

http://phoneguitartab.codeplex.com/

This is tablature viewer for Windows Phone 7. It can open **guitar pro** (.gp3, .gp4, .gp5) and text based files (I've used open source projects in Java to create guitar pro parser in .NET). Unfortunately it isn't finish yet but I hope you find something useful in this project.

Update: GuitarPro functionality was moved into branch

Comment: Excellent, I'll look into it. I just need the parsing code to catalog my tab files, so this should be perfect.

Comment: Hey this is actually some awesome stuff.

Comment: The repo is no longer available. Could you share it elsewhere?