# Read Guitar Pro files with php

Tags: php, parsing, byte, fread, guitar

I want to parse guitar pro files using php. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878012/reading-guitar-pro-files) which directed me to a [description](http://dguitar.sourceforge.net/GP4format.html) of the gp4 format.

As I understand, the file is highly readable :), I just need to know the structure of it. What is the way to do this using php (or maybe javascript)?

Is [this php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) a way to "blindly" parse through the file?

Comment: so what have you tried? where are you stuck? what are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Check phptabs library.It handles midi and guitar pro files. Has a comprehensive sets of API's